# What are the differences between "The Digital Photography" volumes 1, 2 and 3 by Scott Kelby?

Tags: books

I looked through the contents of The Digital Photography Volume 1, 2 and 3 by Scott Kelby  and I noticed that there are repeated chapters (chapters with the same name) like shooting wedding and shooting with flash like a pro, ...

I wonder what are the differences between these chapters, they should have different contents cause these are volumes not editions, so can anyone give more details about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, the first two editions are very useful information and cover separate topics. The third volume is repetitious and contains a lot of information people who are advanced enough to get to the third book have already figured out, so I would skip that one.

Volume 1:

- Pro tips for getting really sharp photos
- Shooting flowers like a pro
- Shooting weddings like a pro
- Shooting landscapes like a pro
- Shooting sports like a pro
- Shooting people like a pro
- Avoiding problems like a pro
- Taking advantage of digital like a pro
- Taking travel and city life shots like a pro
- How to print like a pro and other cool stuff
- Photo Recipes

Volume 2:

- Using Flash like a pro
- Building a studio from scratch
- Shooting portraits like a pro
- Shooting landscapes like a pro
- Shooting weddings like a pro
- Shooting travel like a pro
- Shooting macro like a pro
- Pro Tips for Getting better photos
- More Recipes

Volume 3:

- Using flash like a pro part 2
- Using your studio like a pro
- The truth about lenses
- Shooting products like a pro
- Shooting outdoors like a pro
- Shooting people like a pro
- Shooting sports like a pro
- Pro tips for getting better photos
- Avoiding problems like a pro
- Yet even more photo recipes

Answer (score -2):

There is more information in each of the books.  I got a set for the 1/2 off from Costco.  They're worth a read -- if nothing more they're a nice reminder on the check list that should be embedded in your head.  Worse case you'll learn something new.

Comment: I think the poster was asking for what the differences between the editions are, and not an overview of if you like the books, where you purchased them, etc.